# create javascript code in a php file - SAFARI/CHROME doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome, safari, include

I've created a .php file that write out js code like that:

```
<?
//my_js.php
// javascript header
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
// Date in the past
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
// always modified
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
// HTTP/1.1
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
?>
//
// js code here
//
```

then i include the script above in my index.php file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_js.php?id=<? echo $id ?>">
</script>
```

This works perfect in Firefox, but SAFARI and CHROME doesn't include my_js.php file at all!

What i'm doing wrong?

**edit:

this is the rendered html in index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_js.php?id=new"></script>
```

and this is the my_js.php code:
(it's a very big file so i write out only the first few lines)

```
var g = { sitepath: "myNullUrl" }

function getBrowserWidth(){
if (window.innerWidth){
    return window.innerWidth;}  
else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0){
    return document.documentElement.clientWidth;    }
else if (document.body){return document.body.clientWidth;}      
    return 0;
}
```

that's a strange problem 'cos while i'm viewing source code from Crome/Safari i can access the js file and it seems to be error free!

I'm using Chrome 6.04 and Safari 5, both for mac.

Comment: Please show the finished, rendered HTML. The PHP code is meaningless in this context.

Comment: Please don't use short open tags (`<?` and  `<?=` instead of `<?php` and `<?php echo`) Not only it's not standards compliant but also introduces portability problems.

Comment: Shouldn't the `? >` closing tag create a parse error?

Comment: don't mind the ? > closing tag, that was my fault :)

Comment: `http://localhost:8888` looks like the localhost server provided by MAMP. I use it as well. It's structured that way because you need to type in Administrator password when using designated ports like 80 (HTTP).

Comment: On latest Chrome versions it works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set Content-Disposition: inline; header?

```
        <?php
     if(strstr($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],"MSIE")==false) {
      header("Content-type: text/javascript");
      header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"download.js\"");
      header("Content-Length: ".filesize("my-file.js"));
     } else {
      header("Content-type: application/force-download");
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"download.js\"");
      header("Content-Length: ".filesize("my-file.js"));
     }
     header("Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 2010 05:00:00 GMT");
     if(strstr($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],"MSIE")==false) {
      header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
      header("Pragma: no-cache");
     }
     include("my-file.js

");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It *may* be because it is expecting the file-extension to be my_js.**js**.  If this is the case, save your PHP file as my_js.js, then, assuming you're using Apache, use the Apache Directive: ForceType:

Like so:

```
<Location /your/path/my_js.js>
      ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Location>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hmm, if he's serving the right content type, this shouldn't be a problem: It would be seriously buggy behaviour on the browser's end to expect a certain extension!

Comment: I agree, Pekka, but I have some recollection that eariler versions of Safari (in particular) had this issue - and perhaps still does.  For example, I often see in the error logs that *.js files work fine, but they throw a warning that they were sent with the wrong header.  This would indicate that the browser prefers the extension over the content-type.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Or you can change this:

```
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
```

to this

```
header('Content-type: application/javascript');
```

Note:

- application/javascript: JavaScript; Defined in RFC 4329 but not accepted in IE 8 or earlier
- text/javascript is allowed in HTML 4 and 5 and, unlike application/javascript, has cross-browser support